# Referencing class-level property from initializer

Tags: core-data, swift

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass with an initializer like this:

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {

    convenience init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(preferredEntityName, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        ...
    }

    class var preferredEntityName: String {
        fatalError("This property must be overridden.")
    }

}
```

Compiler says that `Item` does not have a member named `preferredEntityName`. I know I could reference it as `Item.preferredEntityName` but in that case, it's not going work for subclasses.

How could I reference `preferredEntityName` from the initializer so that it will work for subclasses of `Item` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified `Item` class:

```
class Item {

    init(entityName: String) {    
        // Do whatever you want with the entityName
        // Do other common code for all Items
    }

    class var preferredEntityName: String {
        fatalError("This property must be overridden.")
    }

}
```

In your subclass, just pass the `preferredEntityName` after you set it:

```
class ShoppingCartItem: Item {

    var preferredEntityClass = "ShoppingCartItem"

    init() {
        super.init(entityName:preferredEntityClass)
    }

}
```

Comment: Since Swift doesn't have a concept of an abstract, the closest you can get is by using a protocol:

Comment: Now, that is not very helpful. Why can't I reference a class property before `super.init()` call?

Comment: Oh sorry about that...could you tell me what you are trying to achieve with this Item class?  You have a property that isn't implemented in this class and want the subclass to implement it.  When you run the init in your Item class what do you expect to be printed for preferredEntityName?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I've edited the question and tried to be more specific. Basically I want every subclass to have its own entity name and inherit the initializer without need to reimplement it again and again.

Comment: In that case why not put the init in your Item class as you have it, then make a subclass where you set the preferredEntityName.  Just have an init in the subclass that calls the Item class init method with the preferredEntityName as a parameter.  The subclass will not have any other code, its just supplying the value for the preferredEntity which doesn't have any value in the Item class context since it isn't initialized there.  I've updated the code above.

Comment: Now, that's a great idea! Thank you very much for helping me out.